# Perforce auto resolve always accept target

Tags: perforce

I remember that there was a setting, which would always automatically resolve and accept targe without user interaction. However I forgot if this was a server option or a client and not sure how to set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-ay` to the `resolve` command to accept the target ("yours").

See `p4 help resolve`:

```
        The -ay flag resolves all files by accepting yours and ignoring
        theirs. It preserves the content of workspace files.
```

Comment: Is there a way to say which ones to accept? "others" ?

Comment: Which ones of what?  You can provide a file path to say which specific files you want to resolve.  If you want to accept the target for all scheduled resolves, though (as your question indicates), just omit the file path and say `p4 resolve -ay`.  Easy.

Comment: Note that this will *always* result in *discarding* whatever changes were submitted to the depot since you opened the file (or in the case of interfile integration, whatever changes were submitted to the source of the integration).  If you do this in a codebase that other people work on, you'll constantly be rolling back their changes and they will probably be annoyed with you.